# How to bring back default exception mapping that was in Spring Boot 1.5?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, jersey

I have a spring boot Jersey application, I've upgraded it from Spring Boot `1.5.4` (platform: Brussels-SR3) to Boot `2.0.1` (platform: Cairo-RELEASE), which brought Jersey version from `2.25.1` to `2.26`.

Before the upgrade, when application threw an unhandled error, application would have returned a response like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1524060527236, "status": 500, "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.IllegalStateException", "message": "<example message>",
    "path": "/ws/api/example/endpoint"
}
```

after the upgrade the same execution returns:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-04-24T17:00:06.151+0000", "status": 500, "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "<example message>", "path": "/ws/api/example/endpoint"
}
```

I can deal with the different timestamp format, but loosing the exception class is a problem.

I've tried to debug jersey's exception mapping, but I'm not familiar with the code base and it seems quite complex. I couldn't find where does the mapping happen. I also couldn't find any mention in the docs or release notes about changing exception mapping.

Based on the above and comments below, I suppose the change is on Spring side.

So, what changed and how do I get the old behavior back?

Comment: This is from the Spring side not Jersey. Jersey doesn't output that response body. Has nothing to do with Jersey exception mapping.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha thank you, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error response doesn't come from Jersey. It's actually produced when you include the `spring-boot-starter-web` module into your project. Based on [Andy Wilkinson's comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1731#issuecomment-59907352), we can easily override the JSON attributes by creating an `ErrorAttributes` bean. To add the exception, we can just return a [`DefaultErrorAttributes`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/error/DefaultErrorAttributes.html), creating it using the [constructor flag](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/error/DefaultErrorAttributes.html#DefaultErrorAttributes-boolean-) to include the exception.

```
@Bean
public ErrorAttributes errorAttributes() {
    return new DefaultErrorAttributes(true);
}
```

I've tested this and it includes the exception as expected.